# CQRS - Is it "allowed" to publish commands from the domain and/ or read site?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm trying to grasp more of the cqrs concepts. Are commands only sent from clients or is it common to send commands from the domain and/ or projection event listeners?

Let's say that I want to start another business process based on some event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In many cases it makes absolute sense to send commands as a result of another event inside the domain. For example a Saga (as an orchestrator/coordinator of a long-running process) would subscribe to events and submit new commands.

Also system events, like a timeout or an exception or some other circumstance could produce new commands.

In my opinion CQRS woudn't work at all if only a "client" was allowed to submit commands.